# How to force the UICollectionView to animated change with invalidateLayoutWithContext: with my UICollectionViewLayoutInvalidateContext subclass

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I have my `UICollectionViewLayout` subclass for presenting my data with UICollectionView. I have a performance issue when I want to change background color of the supplementary views by calling reloadSections: to UICollectionView (because UICollectionView doesn't provide API to get the supplementary view at index path) which cause the UICollectionViewLayout recalcualte entire the layout attributes. So I write the `UICollectionViewLayoutInvalidationContext` subclass and call invalidatedLayoutWithContext: to the layout which help a lot on the performance issue. BTW the update of the supplementary views is not animated even I call it in the `+[UIView animationWith..]` methods.
So can I force UICollectionView to animating changes in `invalidateLayoutWithContext:`? Or am I doing it wrongs?

PS. I implement `-[UICollectionViewLayout initialLayoutAttributesForAppearingSupplementaryElementOfKind:atIndexPath:]` method, this methods is get called but it's still not animated.

Comment: Have you tried overriding `-[UICollectionViewLayout finalLayoutAttributesForDisappearingSupplementaryElementOfKind:atIndexPath:]`? Every item is removed, then added whenever they have to "move".

Comment: As well as -[UICollectionViewLayout layoutAttributesForSupplementaryElementOfKind:atIndexPath:]

Comment: I've already implemented those methods too. Now I change the way to update that by use different identifier which make the collection view updating with animation.